# Nestjs can not find the module in the dist file

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, nestjs, prisma

I am working on a Nestjs project.
here is my Prisma client - client2.ts:

```
import { PrismaClient as PrismaClient2 } from '../prisma2/generated/client2';
// add prisma to the NodeJS global type
interface CustomNodeJsGlobal {
  prisma2: PrismaClient2;
}
// Prevent multiple instances of Prisma Client in development
declare const global: CustomNodeJsGlobal;
const prisma2 = global.prisma2 || new PrismaClient2();
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
  global.prisma2 = prisma2;
}
prisma2.$on('beforeExit', async () => {
  console.log('beforeExit hook');
  // PrismaClient still available
  await prisma2.$disconnect();
});
export default prisma2;
```

here is my folder struct:

[image]

I can import the prisma client in the client2.ts (no error here) :

```
import { PrismaClient as PrismaClient2 } from '../prisma2/generated/client2';
```

When I run the following:

```
npm run start:dev
```

I get the following error:

```
  Error: Cannot find module '../prisma2/generated/client2'
Require stack:
- /Users/yuxuanche/va/vaproject/frontend/lis-frontend-service/dist/src/client2.js
- /Users/yuxuanche/va/vaproject/frontend/lis-frontend-service/dist/src/trans/trans.service.js
- /Users/yuxuanche/va/vaproject/frontend/lis-frontend-service/dist/src/trans/trans.controller.js
- /Users/yuxuanche/va/vaproject/frontend/lis-frontend-service/dist/src/trans/trans.module.js
- /Users/yuxuanche/va/vaproject/frontend/lis-frontend-service/dist/src/app.module.js
- /Users/yuxuanche/va/vaproject/frontend/lis-frontend-service/dist/src/main.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/yuxuanche/va/vaproject/frontend/lis-frontend-service/src/client2.ts:1:1)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1103:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1157:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
```

So, I go into the dist file and find the client2.js:

[image]

```
"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
const client2_1 = require("../prisma2/generated/client2");
const prisma2 = global.prisma2 || new client2_1.PrismaClient();
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
    global.prisma2 = prisma2;
}
prisma2.$on('beforeExit', async () => {
    console.log('beforeExit hook');
    await prisma2.$disconnect();
});
exports.default = prisma2;
//# sourceMappingURL=client2.js.map
```

If I change:

```
const client2_1 = require("../prisma2/generated/client2");
```

to

```
const client2_1 = require("../../prisma2/generated/client2");
```

I can run the following without error:

```
npm run start:dev
```

Am I missing something here?

here is my tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "declaration": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "target": "es2017",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "incremental": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strictNullChecks": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "strictBindCallApply": false,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": false,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": false
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It was just solved!

I am using:

```
const { PrismaClient } = require('../../prisma2/generated/client2');
```

Everything is good; fingers crossed

Answer (score 0):

When building a NestJS application, the `prisma/generated` folder is missing in the dist directory. This occurs because the dist folder only contains `src` and `prisma/seeders` folders, and it gets automatically removed and rebuilt when starting the application (`npm run start:dev`).

The solution for this is as follows,

**Manual Copy:**
Manually copy the `generated` folder from the Prisma directory into the `prisma` folder within the `dist` directory. This ensures that the generated Prisma files are available in the correct location after the build.

**Update nest-cli.json:**
Set `"deleteOutDir": false` in the `nest-cli.json` file to prevent the deletion of the dist folder during the build process. This allows the generated folder to persist in the dist directory.

The sample configuration is attached below.

[image: Sample configuration Attached]